# Trying to call a function in an unknown DLL

Tags: windows, x86-64, .net

My goal is far from nefarious. After several polite attempts to try and get Lenovo to implement a proper keyboard backlight control, I've had no response.
They do have a Windows Store app which adds that control, however, it's not tied to keyboard or mouse input (idle user time). I can implement that, with AutoHotKey, if I manage to call their methods.

Screenshots for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGBre.jpg

Using JetBrains I can see a quite readable code, written in .NET (I assume), my main interest is in Keyboard_Core.dll. There I can see the methods for getting and setting the keyboard backlight, but I don't understand how they work.

```
public unsafe uint SetKeyboardBackLightStatus(int nStatus)
{
  CKeyboardLight* ckeyboardLightPtr1 = (CKeyboardLight*) <Module>.@new(4U);
  CKeyboardLight* ckeyboardLightPtr2;
  // ISSUE: fault handler
  try
  {
    ckeyboardLightPtr2 = (IntPtr) ckeyboardLightPtr1 == IntPtr.Zero ? (CKeyboardLight*) 0 : <Module>.ThinkPad.CKeyboardLight.{ctor}(ckeyboardLightPtr1);
  }
  __fault
  {
    <Module>.delete((void*) ckeyboardLightPtr1);
  }
  <Module>.ThinkPad.CKeyboardLight.SetStatus(ckeyboardLightPtr2, (KBDLIGHT_STATUS) nStatus);
  if ((IntPtr) ckeyboardLightPtr2 != IntPtr.Zero)
  {
    CKeyboardLight* ckeyboardLightPtr3 = ckeyboardLightPtr2;
    int num = 1;
    // ISSUE: cast to a function pointer type
    // ISSUE: function pointer call
    void* voidPtr = __calli((__FnPtr<void* (IntPtr, uint)>) *(int*) *(int*) ckeyboardLightPtr2)((uint) ckeyboardLightPtr3, (IntPtr) num);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand where @new(4U) points to. In the decompiled declaration it says it's `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 4)]` - so I can probably work with that without any structure description. Is it later pointed to some real memory address?
I cannot figure that out, it seems that both `ckeyboardLightPtr1` and `ckeyboardLightPtr2` are new objects until the end of the function.

I don't know how to call a random address (function) with some prepared parameters (stack) - should I stick to AHK (then it would be a different question), try Python (another layer), PowerShell (never used it) or create a small C program?

Either way, it looks that I have to set 4 bytes somewhere in memory. Perhaps I'm chasing the wrong end and these functions just set a temporary/proxy object that is later handled by a monitor thread.

https://pastebin.com/vyfiTTcr

Ollydbg doesn't let me do anything with the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

`@new(4U)` points to an external function that this DLL uses via P/Invoke. I don't have Jetbrains dotPeek installed right now but if you do it in dnSpy - you can click on the `@new` and you will be taken to the method.

[image]

> Is it later pointed to some real memory address?

I would assume that's it's just allocates the memory and returns the pointer that's assigned to `ckeyboardLightPtr1` and then later it is used in the call to `<Module>.ThinkPad.CKeyboardLight.{ctor}`.

> I don't know how to call a random address (function) with some prepared parameters (stack) - should I stick to AHK (then it would be a different question), try Python (another layer), PowerShell (never used it) or create a small C program?

Not sure to what random function you are referring to but I guess you can choose what's best for you. I would use .NET ;)

> Either way, it looks that I have to set 4 bytes somewhere in memory.

yes, it does look like that.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually pretty easy to do in Visual Studio with a bit of basic research.
I created a console application, the main functionality is contained within these lines:

```
            Assembly myAssembly;
            //full path to dll
            myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(args[0]);

            object obj;
            Type myType = myAssembly.GetType("Keyboard_Core.KeyboardControl");
            obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
            IEnumerable list = myType.GetMethods();
            MethodInfo setKeyboardBackLightStatusInfo = GetRuntimeMethodsExt(myType, "SetKeyboardBackLightStatus");


            object[] arguments = new object[] { Int32.Parse(args[1]) };
            UInt32 output = (UInt32)setKeyboardBackLightStatusInfo.Invoke(obj, arguments);
```

The "list" parameter is useless for normal usage but useful when debugging. With that, it's easy to see what the available functions are and their signature.

args[0] points to the absolute path of the DLL, including its name.

args[1] is the int parameter to be given to the function.

I used a modified version of the answer linked below, to avoid having to manually give Type parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307845/runtimereflectionextensions-getruntimemethod-does-not-work-as-expected

The modified (unsafe) version is basically this:

```
    static MethodInfo GetRuntimeMethodsExt(this Type type, string name)
    {
        var potentials = (from ele in type.GetMethods()
                          where ele.Name.Equals(name)
                          select ele);

        // Maybe check if we have more than 1? Or not?
        return potentials.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```